# Programmable Control of Niagara

Tags: niagara-ax

How to make an external program control Tridium Niagara framework? I see two options; Which one is correct:

1) Niagara allows addition of 3rd party code to provide an API, and someone else has already done that and we can use it.

2) Niagara allows 3rd party code to do API but we have to write our own.

Answer (score 1):

Niagara installations can be configured to process many different network control protocols driven by an external process across the network, for example by BACnet. The Niagara instance can be configured internally in many different ways to respond to control from across the network.

Niagara 4.x prominently features Web GUIs, including Javascript client widgets and server Javascript, or the server can respond to the Web GUI activity with its other configuration and scripting methods.

For any real complexity beyond the bundled network drivers or HTTP, 3rd party modules coded in Java are used. These would typically be coded as Niagara drivers, processing data over serial or sockets.

Niagara's APIs are mostly open. But Niagara is a complex environment. Completing Tridium's week-long developer training/certification is typically required to produce a proper module.

Answer (score 0):

There are some external API's that Tridium built into AX. oBIX and Bajascript.

I've written external oBIX programs in both Java and Python to pull data from a remote Jace. You'll have to add the oBIX service and export the points you want to see.

Bajascript is a javascript library Tridium uses to interact with the system as well. I believe they released Bajascript 2.0 not to long ago. http://www.bajascript.com

If those don't do what you like, you'll more than likely need to write your own API to handle it.